# angular.forEach with .find

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am searching for a specific field and when found, assign it to a new variable. This works fine as long as the value exist. If it doesn't exist in one record, stops.

```
angular.forEach($scope.allnews.entries, function (value) {
    value.articleImage = $(value.content).find('img').eq(0).attr('src');
});
```

`$scope.allnews.entries` contains a big chunk of json data. The field content contains the img data I am interested about. However, sometimes the content field may not contain any img. As an example,

```
Record 1: contains img
Record 2: contains img
Record 3: contains img
Record 4: does not contains img
Record 5: does not contains img
Record 6: contains img
Record 7: contains img
```

My problem is that when I bind `articleImage`, I will only get the img for record 1, 2 and 3. It will stop retrieving the value for the rest, in this case 6 and 7 won't show anything. Is there a way I can put a condition in this loop so when it doesn't found it adds an empty tag or it doesn't stop? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just test to see if the element exists before trying to get the `src` attribute from it.

```
angular.forEach($scope.allnews.entries, function (value) {
    var img = $(value.content).find('img').eq(0);
    value.articleImage = img ? img.attr('src') : null;
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much Alexis, I just tried this and unfortunately I still get the same result :(, stops after it founds the last img, in this case record 3

Comment: @carol1287 Are you getting any errors in the JavaScript console? If so, please include them in your question.

Comment: excellent point Alexis, thanks again, I couldn't see any error and I added a try/catch and now I can see it: Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression on record 4. Basically I am getting an RSS feed and it seems there is something in that record that breaks everything.

Comment: because I do not have control of the RSS data, is there a way I could say if there is an error skip it and continue ?

Comment: I just look at the data and value.content for record 4 and 5 doesn't contain any img tag inside and I believe that's why it crashes

Comment: problem solved! I had the try/catch outside the loop, oops!  now it works, thanks so much Alexis for all your help and help me open my eyes more :-)